# TradingView is not defined in Vue mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, tradingview-api

I don't know if I should ask a question here or other place, but I am using `tradingview` library, which works for me, but not how I want to.

According to docs I put my code into `index.html` file in vue, under script tag and my `tradingview` works, however I want to put this code under `mounted`, but I get this error:

> Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: TradingView is not defined"

Here is example of code in `index.html` file which works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/charting_library/charting_library.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
<script>

function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

TradingView.onready(function() {
  var widget = new TradingView.widget({
    symbol: 'Bitfinex:ETHUSD',
    interval: '30',
    theme: 'Dark',
    style: '1',
    container_id: "tv_chart_container",
    library_path: "/charting_library/",
    locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",
    width: '100%',
    height: '600px',
    debug: false,
    preset: "mobile"
  });
```

})

And here is the code of mounted in my vue file:

```
mounted () {
TradingView.onready(function() {
  new TradingView.widget({
    symbol: 'Bitfinex:ETHUSD',
    interval: '30',
    theme: 'Dark',
    style: '1',
    container_id: "tv_chart_container",
    library_path: "/charting_library/",
    locale: this.getParameterByName('lang') || "en",
    width: '100%',
    height: '600px',
    debug: false,
    preset: 'mobile'
  })
})
}
```

Does anyone know why `TradingView` is not defined here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone will have the same issue, so for me *setTimeout* did the trick. Here is the code:

```
mounted () {
  setTimeout(function() {
   // TradingView code
  }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to use `vue` script so add it as follow :

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
```

check this working code :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
   
     
     }
  },
 mounted () {
TradingView.onready(function() {
  new TradingView.widget({
    symbol: 'Bitfinex:ETHUSD',
    interval: '30',
    theme: 'Dark',
    style: '1',
    container_id: "tv_chart_container",
    library_path: "/charting_library/",
    locale: this.getParameterByName('lang') || "en",
    width: '100%',
    height: '600px',
    debug: false,
    preset: 'mobile'
  })
})
}
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/charting_library/charting_library.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script>

function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

</script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```